# Overload server django deploy with apache2 and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm with several problem with overload at deploy django with apache2 and mod_wsgi.
Follow my steps and setup:

Server: Ubuntu 18.04 running at Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL).

Install

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-dev python3-pip virtualenv
apache2 apache2-dev mysql-server phpmyadmin php-mbstring
php-gettex libmysqlclient-dev
```

So, I created a vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 127.0.0.20
        ServerAlias divisor.local

        ErrorLog /mnt/d/divisor/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /mnt/d/divisor/logs/access.log combined
       #provide from mod_wsgi-express --conf
       LoadModule wsgi_module "/mnt/d/divisor/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"


        Alias /static /mnt/d/divisor/framework/static
        Alias /media /mnt/d/divisor/framework/media

        <Directory /mnt/d/divisor/framework>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
                </Files>
         </Directory>

        <Directory /mnt/d/divisor/framework/media/>
                Require all granted
         </Directory>

         <Directory /mnt/d/divisor/framework/static/>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /mnt/d/divisor/framework/framework/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess divisor display-name=divisor-modwsgi python-path=/mnt/d/divisor/framework/:/mnt/d/divisor/env3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup divisor
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

</VirtualHost>
```

With virtualenv active I run:

```
pip install django mod_wsgi
```

When I run apache start. Less than 3 seconds apache overload with 2 proccess. Follow "top" on terminal:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6272 www-data  18 42+  318844  31608   8692 S 100.7  0.4   0:13.21 apache2
 6274 www-data  18 42+ 2017236   8668   3924 S 100.7  0.1   0:12.29 apache2
```

I try found the problem with sudo lsof -p 6272, log

```
apache2 6272 www-data    0r      CHR    1,3        65583669573738507 /dev/null
apache2 6272 www-data    1w      CHR    1,3        65583669573738507 /dev/null
apache2 6272 www-data    3u     sock    0,0                     8978 can't identify protocol
apache2 6272 www-data    5r     FIFO    0,0                     8995 pipe
apache2 6272 www-data    6w     FIFO    0,0                     8995 pipe
apache2 6272 www-data    8w      REG    0,2      0   562949954063676 /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
apache2 6272 www-data    9w      REG   0,13  19168   281474976719069 /mnt/d/divisor/logs/access.log
apache2 6272 www-data   10w      REG    0,2  27268   562949954063675 /var/log/apache2/access.log
apache2 6272 www-data   11u     sock    0,0                     8996 can't identify protocol
apache2 6272 www-data    4r     FIFO    0,0                     8997 pipe
apache2 6272 www-data   12w     FIFO    0,0                     8997 pipe
apache2 6272 www-data    2w      REG   0,13  77784   281474976719068 /mnt/d/divisor/logs/error.log
apache2 6272 www-data    7u  unknown                                 /unknown (stat: Operation not permitted)
apache2 6272 www-data   13u     sock    0,0                     9004 can't identify protocol
apache2 6272 www-data   14u  unknown                                 /unknown (stat: Operation not permitted)
```

Otherwise, I try found more error using  `mod_wsgi-express start-server`. And overload apache2 again. See log:

```
Server URL         : http://localhost:8000/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:1000
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:1000/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:1000/error_log (warn)
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Startup Timeout    : 15 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.UTF-8
```

Getting mod_wsgi-express logs:

```
sudo tail /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:1000/error_log

[Tue Jun 26 06:32:28.370796 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6145:tid 140319572036544] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 26 06:32:44.994203 2018] [core:warn] [pid 6199:tid 140624007269312] (92)Protocol not available: AH00076: Failed to enable APR_TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT
[Tue Jun 26 06:32:45.002138 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6199:tid 140624007269312] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 26 06:32:45.002276 2018] [core:notice] [pid 6199:tid 140624007269312] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 (mod_wsgi-express) -f /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:1000/httpd.conf -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_ENABLE_EVENT_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_EVENT_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_WORKER_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_PREFORK_MODULE -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Jun 26 06:34:27.996234 2018] [core:warn] [pid 6199:tid 140624007269312] AH00045: child process 6202 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Jun 26 06:34:30.006839 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6199:tid 140624007269312] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 26 06:59:14.916257 2018] [core:warn] [pid 6353:tid 140711608388544] (92)Protocol not available: AH00076: Failed to enable APR_TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT
[Tue Jun 26 06:59:14.928841 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6353:tid 140711608388544] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 26 06:59:14.928973 2018] [core:notice] [pid 6353:tid 140711608388544] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 (mod_wsgi-express) -f /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:1000/httpd.conf -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_ENABLE_EVENT_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_EVENT_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_WORKER_MODULE -D MOD_WSGI_MPM_EXISTS_PREFORK_MODULE -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Jun 26 07:00:07.208780 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6353:tid 140711608388544] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

print [file sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQE9v.png)

I hope can get explain correctly my problem.

Comment: I solved partially the problem fixing ` processes=5 threads=10 maximum-requests=100 request-timeout=5`  I'm not sure if I must use this setup in production enviroment. @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Finally I Solve this. The problem was on Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL). Apache don't work well in subsystem on window later Ubuntu 14.04. I used a virtuabox and all works fine. Thanks @GrahamDumpleton for you attention. Regards

Comment: I got the same issue. The only difference is that the project Im working on uses python 2.7 .